# zapier cli app custom trigger sending duplicate fields to action app after pushed a new version

Tags: jquery, zapier, zapier-cli

I have attached a screenshot where I am mapping output fileds sending from my custom trigger of zapier cli app. Everyhing is working fine but showing duplicate fields as you can see it on below image.
[image: Output Fileds]

Comment: hey! that looks like a bug on our end. Can you write into partners@zapier.com with your app id and we can take a closer look?

Comment: @xavdid already sent zap link

Comment: @xavdid I am facing the same issue. I tried updating version , changing data but nothing worked. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I would also write into `partners@` with your app id. It looks like this bug was originally fixed in october